# How to solve "unexpected keyword argument" error

Tags: python

```
import folium
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes.txt")
lat = list(data["LAT"]) 
lon = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])

def  color_distributor(elev):
    if elev < 1000:
        return "red"
    elif elev >= 1000 and elev < 3000:
        return "orange"    
    else:
        return "green"

map =  folium.Map(location=[30, 100], zoom_start=5)
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

for lt, ln, el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius=6, popup=str(el) + " m",
    fill_color=color_distributor(el)), color='grey', fill_opacity=0.7)

map.add_child(fg)
map.save("map1.html")
```

***ERROR***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\STUDY\My Programs\Applications\App 2.py", line 21, in <module>
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius=6, popup=str(el) + " m",
TypeError: add_child() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

Comment: My suspicion is you have a misplaced `)`. `color='grey'` and `fill_opacity=0.7` are probably intended for `CircleMarker()`, not `fg.add_child()`.

Comment: Just so you know, "HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS ISSUE HELEP PLZ" is not a title that will attract anyone willing to answer any kind of serious question.

Answer (score 0):

We can see from the error message that this is the problematic line:

```
fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius=6, popup=str(el) + " m",
    fill_color=color_distributor(el)), color='grey', fill_opacity=0.7)
```

We can understand that easier with some formatting:

```
fg.add_child(
  folium.CircleMarker(
    location=[lt, ln],
    radius=6,
    popup=str(el) + " m",
    fill_color=color_distributor(el)
  ),
  color='grey',
  fill_opacity=0.7
)
```

`fg` is a Folium FeatureGroup. The `add_child` method is being sent three things, which are a `CircleMarker`, `color` and `fill_opacity`. If we check out the documentation: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html we see that this method doesn't have a `color` or `fill_opacity` parameter.

This is also seen in the error message:

> TypeError: add_child() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'

Interestingly, `CircleMarker` has both of those parameters: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circlemarker (they are part of the Path).

I would therefore suggest that `color` and `fill_opacity` are intended to be parameters for the `CircleMarker` and not `add_child`.

So the correct line would be:

```py
fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius=6, popup=str(el) + " m",
    fill_color=color_distributor(el), color='grey', fill_opacity=0.7))
```